# Print an array in table form in TCL

Tags: arrays, printing, tcl

I am trying to print an array to a file using:

```
for {set i 0} {$i <= 9} {incr i} {

    set  j $i
    incr j
    set depth($j) [operation]
}
```

How can I print a two-dimensional matrix with range `j` in 1st row and range `depth` in 2nd row:

```
Level: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Value: a b c d e f g h i j
```

I have tried below code:

```
set FH [open tmp.txt w]

foreach keyVal [lsort -dic [array names depth]] {

        puts  -nonewline $FH " $keyVal\t"
}

puts $FH ""

foreach keyVal [lsort -dic [array names depth]] {

        puts  -nonewline $FH "$depth($keyVal)\t"
}

puts $FH ""

close $FH
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

a b c d e f g h i j
```

Comment: Except for the labels ("Level:" and "Value:") it seems like you are getting the output you wanted. Is there any other problem? Your code is a bit inefficient, and you are showing us a one-dimensional array instead of the two-dimensional you are talking about, but I think more information is needed before an answer can be made.

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be seen by eyes instead of being a tab-separated CSV, you'll want to ensure that the columns line up properly.

```
# some test data
array set depth {
  1   qwerty
  2   foo
  333 x
  444 bar
}

set sep ""   ; # the field separator
foreach key [lsort -integer [array names depth]] {
    set wid [expr {max([string length $key],[string length $depth($key)])}]
    # or, less bracket-y
    set wid [tcl::mathfunc::max [string length $key] [string length $depth($key)]]

    append row1 [format {%s%-*d} $sep $wid $key]
    append row2 [format {%s%-*s} $sep $wid $depth($key)]
    set sep " "
}

puts $row1
puts $row2
```

outputs

```
1      2   333 444 
qwerty foo x   bar
```